# Can't connect with facebook through facebook app on ios

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My problems is kind a strange. I created facebook app, to which I connect via js through iFrame. dummy link : http://kvizblic.com/test/koliko-staro-izgledas
I plugged that iFrame on other subdomain of the same site, and everything works fine.  But when someone share my quiz on facebook, and you try to open the quiz through facebook app(not browser), and click on "Login with Facebook" nothing happens. This happen only on iPhone. If I try to do the same thing on android or desktop, everything works fine.
Maybe this is confusing, so once again.
My quiz is loading through iFrame on other subdomain of the same site. Quiz have Login with facebook button. When you click on that button, I contact facebook for your data via js "FB.login" and everything works fine.
But if you visit the same link through facebook app(after someone share it), and not browser, Login with facebook doesn't work. That happens only on iPhone(haven't check iPad). On android everything works fine.

Comment: If this works on all platforms but one I would raise a bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Solved it. Didn't approach problem from right direction. The problem is that FB.login is not working through Web View. Only solution was to hit "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?..." directly.
reported bug on facebook, and after 10 days got reply that they receive my report...

Comment: Next time report the bug through the Facebook developer bug tool - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. That won't take 10 days to get a response!